# Disable swiping on a view

Tags: java, android

I am using this package to achieve a Tinder-like swiping feature - https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

However, I want to disable swiping and instead use buttons for the "like" and "dislike". This package does not seem to have inherent ability to disable swiping. I created a custom class to extend this package and implemented a feature to allow me disable swiping but this does not work.

Here is the custom class:

```
package com.xxxx.xxxx.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;

public class CustomSwipeFlingAdapterView extends SwipeFlingAdapterView {

    private boolean isSwipeEnabled = true;

    public CustomSwipeFlingAdapterView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwipeFlingAdapterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSwipeFlingAdapterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setSwipeEnabled(boolean swipeEnabled) {
        isSwipeEnabled = swipeEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return isSwipeEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return isSwipeEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Here is my activity file:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;
import com.you4me.you4me.adapter.CustomSwipeFlingAdapterView;
import com.xxxx.xxxxx.models.Person;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindDateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomSwipeFlingAdapterView flingAdapterView;
    private VideoAdapter videoAdapter;

    private TextView name;
    private TextView address;
    private TextView paying;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_date);

        flingAdapterView=findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("https://xxxxxxxxx.mp4", "All hands Memorial College, New York", "Rick", "Together", "24"));
        persons.add(new Person(("https://xxxxxxxxx.mp4", "KingFisher Restaurant", "James", "Together", "45"
        ));
        persons.add(new Person(("https://xxxxxxxxx.mp4", "The Place Restaurant", "Angel", "Separately", "33"
        ));
//
        videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(persons);
        flingAdapterView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
        flingAdapterView.setSwipeEnabled(false);

        flingAdapterView.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                if (videoAdapter.getCount() != 0) {
                   videoAdapter.remove(videoAdapter.getItem(0));
                    videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object o) {

                videoAdapter.setCurrentPosition(-1); // Stop playback when card is swiped left
                videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(FindDateActivity.this,"dislike",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object o) {
                videoAdapter.setCurrentPosition(-1);
                videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(FindDateActivity.this,"like",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float v) {

            }
        });

        flingAdapterView.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int i, Object o) {
                videoAdapter.setCurrentPosition(i);
               
            }
        });



        Button like,dislike;

        like=findViewById(R.id.like);
        dislike=findViewById(R.id.dislike);

        like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentPosition = flingAdapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // Get the current selected position
                if (currentPosition != SwipeFlingAdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    flingAdapterView.getTopCardListener().selectRight();
                }
            }
        });

        dislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentPosition = flingAdapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // Get the current selected position
                if (currentPosition != SwipeFlingAdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    flingAdapterView.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

        private int currentPosition = -1;
        VideoAdapter(List<Person> persons) {
            super(FindDateActivity.this, 0, persons);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            }

            FrameLayout frameLayout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoContainer);
            frameLayout.removeAllViews(); // Remove any previous VideoView

            VideoView videoView = new VideoView(getContext());
            videoView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            Person person = getItem(position);
            if (person != null) {
                String videoUrl = person.getVideoLink();
                if (videoUrl != null) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
                    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

                    TextView nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                    TextView addressTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
                    TextView payingTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPaying);

                    nameTextView.setText(person.getName());
                    addressTextView.setText(person.getPlace());
                    payingTextView.setText(person.getPayment());



                    // You can also set up media controller if needed
                    final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getContext());
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

                    // Set a callback for when the video is prepared to start playing
                    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            if (position == currentPosition) {
                                videoView.start();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    videoView.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            frameLayout.addView(videoView);

            return convertView;
        }
        public void setCurrentPosition(int position) {
            currentPosition = position;
        }
    }

}
```

`activity_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dislike"
            android:text="dislike"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="like"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/like"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.CustomSwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/line1"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.0"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`item.layout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="337dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- TextViews outside the video FrameLayout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoContainer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewName"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView3"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPaying"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewAddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How else can I achieve this?